# Equivalence between ghosts?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, unitarity, brst, ghosts

Ok. I'm trying to get the terminology right about the term [ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_(physics)) in physics. Is there any equivalence between these terms?

- Faddeev-Popov ghosts
- Paul-Villars ghosts
- Landau ghost
- The vanishing Goldstone bosons in electroweak symmetry breaking

Does any of these terms encapsulates one of the others?

Does the term [antighost](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antighost) apply to any of these?

Comment: There's no such term in physics. There are individual terms, which you nicely enumerated ;)

Answer (score 2):

All they have in common is being unphysical. Faddeev-Popov ghosts can't be observed as particles because they violate the spin-statistics tension; Pauli-Villars ghosts are negative-norm states; the Landau pole tells you your theory must give way to another at high energies; Goldstone ghosts represent an unphysical artefact of gauge fixing.